# Anbox isn't getting installed in 17.04

Tags: snap, 17.04, anbox

Anbox isn't getting installed at all in 17.04 it worked in 16.10, I tried this command

```
sudo snap install --classic anbox-installer && anbox-installer
```

I found these lines to be errors in installation process

```
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/alex-wv/pulseaudio-equalizer-ppa/ubuntu zesty Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Full installation log is posted here at [Paste Ubuntu](https://paste.ubuntu.com/24479743/)

---

I think this is happening because it doesn't support 17.04 yet and support will be added at some point later, my another question is is their some sort of [Backward compatibility](https://superuser.com/questions/926793/do-windows-10-backward-compatible-with-windows-7-api-and-drivers) like feature in Ubuntu (it' present in windows)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you're experiencing is you've add a PPA which doesn't have any software published for Ubuntu 17.04 (Zesty Zapus). Remove the entry for [Alex WV PPA](https://launchpad.net/~alex-wv/+archive/ubuntu/pulseaudio-equalizer-ppa) in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` and `andbox-installer` will work again.

you can also run

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:alex-wv/pulseaudio-equalizer-ppa
```

and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> when asked to confirm

Answer (score 0):

[This guide](https://github.com/anbox/anbox/wiki/Installation) guide from Github worked well for me.
Here is an abstract of what I did from the [guide](https://github.com/anbox/anbox/wiki/Installation) and google.

1. Install snap package manager from apt

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get install snaps
   ```

   Alternatively, you can use Synaptic Package Manager to search and install snaps.
2. Install anbox using snap

   ```
   $ sudo snap install --edge --devmode anbox
   ```
3. Install additional packages to support anbox kernel modules

   ```
   $ sudo apt install -y software-properties-common linux-header-generic
   $ sudo add-apt-repository -y 'ppa:morphis/anbox-support'
   $ sudo apt update
   $ sudo apt install -y anbox-modules-dkms
   ```
4. Now you have installed anbox. Issue the following single command to install essential dependencies

   ```
   $ sudo apt install build-essential cmake cmake-data debhelper dbus google-mock libboost-dev libboost-filesystem-dev libboost-log-dev libboost-iostreams-dev libboost-program-options-dev libboost-system-dev libboost-test-dev libboost-thread-dev libcap-dev libdbus-1-dev libdbus-cpp-dev libegl1-mesa-dev libgles2-mesa-dev libglib2.0-dev libglm-dev libgtest-dev liblxc1 libproperties-cpp-dev libprotobuf-dev libsdl2-dev libsdl2-image-dev lxc-dev pkg-config protobuf-compiler
   ```
5. For installing apps in anbox android, you will need adb and adb tools. Install them with the follwoing command

   ```
   $sudo apt install adb
   $sudo apt install android-tools-adb
   ```
6. Done! Now, to launch and install apps, use the following command

   ```
   $ anbox session-manager
   ```
7. Once the anbox window shows up, install apps using the following command, and wait to see success message in the terminal

   ```
   $ adb install /app_folder/your_app.apk
   ```

   Replace app_folder/your_app.apk with the path of the apk file you want to install.

The above steps should work fine. However, anbox has certain functionality limitations associated with google services. Rest assured it is smooth and fast than other emulators on linux.

Answer (score 0):

Just a warning that Andbox rebuilds several kernel modules that interfere with subsequent display driver upgrades.

This results in occasionally being forced to reinstall display drivers.

The following will remedy this situation:

```
sudo apt purge andbox*
sudo dpkg –configure -a
```